# Multiple Select with duplicate value | Antd Select Component

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown, antd

So I have Antd multiple `Select` component with this configuration:

```js
<Select
 fieldNames={{ label: 'name', value: 'id' }}
 mode="multiple"
 showSearch
 options={optionsData}
/>
```

My `optionsData` is an array of items, each has unique value. The component already can select multiple option, but what I want is that it can select/pick the same option more than one. So the selected options can have duplicated options with same value. I've tried to read the docs and surfing around internet but couldn't find any solution to config this multiple select.

**How to set Antd Select so it can select/pick multiple options with same/duplicated value?**

If it can't, is there any alternative library to create this kind of component behaviour? (able to connect with Antd Form would be great) Thanks